# Azure DevOps Hosted Agent: The 'SQLNCLI11.1' provider is not registered on the local machine error

Tags: sql, azure-devops, azure-devops-hosted-agent

we were recently using the agent configuration 'vs2017-win2016' to run our automated tests in Azure DevOps. However, we've had to upgrade to the configuration 'windows-latest' recently due to this being deprecated, and we've suddenly started getting the error `'The 'SQLNCLI11.1' provider is not registered on the local machine'`  when trying to connect to a SQL Database to pull back data.

I've done a bit of googling, and it sounds like these agents are missing the Microsoft Access Database Engine which is why it's failing. Has anyone found a workaround for this? Using Self-Hosted agents isn't really an option as we require resources to set them up that aren't available to us, along with a budget we don't have for it. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

The connection string I am using to connect is:

`"Server=tcp:" + server + ",1433;Initial Catalog = " + initialCatalog + ";Persist Security Info=False;User ID = " + username + ";Password=" + password + ";MultipleActiveResultSets=False;Encrypt=True;TrustServerCertificate=False;Connection Timeout=30;Provider=SQLNCLI11.1"`

where 'server', 'initialCatalog', 'username' and 'password' are parameters we pass in.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like SQLNCLI is deprecated and you should use MSOLEDB

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/oledb/oledb-driver-for-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15

I imagine it has been removed from the build agent to encourage migration

Here are some sample connection strings

https://www.connectionstrings.com/ole-db-driver-for-sql-server/

Does this connection string work:

```
"Provider=MSOLEDBSQL;Server=tcp:" + server + ",1433;Database = " + initialCatalog + ";UID = " + username + ";PWD=" + password + ";"
```

There are more sample sqloledb connection strings here

https://www.connectionstrings.com/microsoft-ole-db-provider-for-sql-server-sqloledb/

Comment: Perfect, this fixed it for me. Thank you!